# Facebook bottom bar state

Tags: javascript, facebook, session-state

What's the best way to keep state in a bottom bar that sticks to the UI, even when different pages are navigated to? Let's say I was programming Facebook and wanted to keep all open conversations the same, etc with the most efficiency. I could use something like [jixedbar](http://ryan.rawswift.com/sandbox/jixedbar-0.0.2/demo/) (is there a better solution?) for the bar, but not sure how to keep state best.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to implement something like Facebook Chat in the bottom bar, just read how they did it. A lot of what they use is open source (i.e. Thrift).
http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=14218138919
http://www.scribd.com/doc/22428456/Erlang-at-Facebook

Comment: Interesting. A pretty complex solution.

Comment: thats because of how high it needs to scale.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use session cookies so it can be printed again in the same state.